# Toggling Event Listeners on and off programmatically

Tags: .net, events, event-handling, slider

I have a `Slider` whose value can be changed either by user, or through the code (e.g. `slider.Value = 20;`.

There is also an event listener for the slider, `ValueChanged`. 
However, I want to suppress the call to the event handler when changing its value programmatically. That is, i dont want the `slider.Value = 20;` fire the event.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice the slider creates a line in the designer:

```
this.slider.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.OnValueChanged);
```

This binds the event to the event handler.  You can remove this programatically:

```
this.slider.ValueChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.OnValueChanged);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry - I'm assuming C#, I don't know the VB syntax